# BSD Shell date command validation is accepting invalid date

Tags: macos, shell, date

I am using `date` in BSD Shell to validate a date like below:

```
date -f "%Y.%m.%d" -j "2021.01.01" >/dev/null 2>&1 && is_valid=true || is_valid=false
```

Generally, the above command works well. If, however I enter the date `2021.01.00` I.e. day is `0`, `is_valid` return `true`, meaning it is considered as a valid date.

**Why is this happening?**

I think this is happening because the `date` command is interpreting day `00` as the last day of the previous month:

command:

```
date -f "%Y.%m.%d" -j "2021.04.00"
```

outputs:

```
Wed Mar 31 09:38:50 CEST 2021
```

This is not the output I desire. I would rather the command returns an error as invalid input.

Comment: This is tagged bash, but bash is not a "BSD shell". Which OS is this? Also, on FreeBSD, the date 2021.01.00 is reported as invalid.

Comment: @Jens updated tags. My apologies. I am using mac OS which Is using FreeBSD to my knowledge. Updated questions also

Comment: It would seem, Apple has not kept up with changes in FreeBSD's `date` implementation. Does Apple accept bug reports in some form?